# How to execute client-side code before server-side code in VB?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, code-behind

I'm trying to execute server-side code first on a button click, for this I tried following code which is still executing client side first.

```
<script runat="server">
        Protected Sub view_doc_hide_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles view_doc_hide.Click
            Dim dt1 As DataTable
            Dim objTS1 As New clsTS
            Dim earn_code As String
            earn_code = hdnDoctemprecord.Value
            dt1 = objTS1 .DOCdetails(CInt(hdnEmployeeSeq.Value), earn_code)
            hdnappdocseq.Value = dt1.Rows.Item(0).Item("Item1")

        End Sub
</script>

<asp:Button ID="view_doc_hide" OnClick="view_doc_hide_Click" OnClientClick=" return after_click_viewdoc();"  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" runat="server" Text="Save" />
```

Any ideas what about what I am missing here? Thanks

Comment: Client side code will always be executed first. Why do you want to do this? Explain the full situation and you might get a good alternativE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do defeats the purpose of the client-server model. All validation should first be done on the client side, and any extra validation for example check if a user exists in a database should be done on the server side.

To answer your question you could maybe just do nothing on the client side first, send all the info to your server and on your response back do whatever you need to do on the client side again. I advise you restructure your code because this is not best practice